# Wordpress Post__not_in not working when supplied through variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a function and passing dynamically the comma separated values to wp_args. When i echo variable i get the exact as needed and passing statci gies result but while passing variable name, I do not get results.

```
$excludepages1 = "12,14";
$excludepages2 = "'".implode("','", explode(",", $excludepages1))."'";
$excludepages = str_replace('"', '', $excludepages2);
```

Now If i echo `$excludepages` I get `'12','14'`
But when i pass here

```
$children = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' =>'page',
        'posts_per_page' =>-1,
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post__not_in' => array($excludepages)));
```

I do not get any result and if instead of variable i pass `'12','14'`, I get results, Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

```
$excludepages1 = "12,14";
$excludepages = explode(",", $excludepages1);
```

An exploded array can be used directly.

"exclude" param is suggested in the docs. So, I used instead of "post__not_in".

```
$children = get_posts( array(
                'post_type' =>'page',
                'posts_per_page' =>-1,
                'post_parent' => $post_id,
                'orderby' => 'menu_order',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'exclude' => $excludepages)
            );
```

Comment: I tried using exclude but no result. As said in question, issue is with variable so like passing static gives result whereas passing variable is not giving result even when it echo's the same result.

Comment: Have you updated `$excludepages` variable like above code?

Answer (score 1):

Doing it the way you are you are creating an array with a 0 index and value of "12,14." What you are doing is passing a string "12, 14" to the first index of an array. What you want to do is pass two integers into an array. So if you print array($excludepages) the way you're doing it you'll see

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12,14
)
```

What you want is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 14,
)
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the implodes, explodes, and str_replace, but you'll want to define your array using something like:

```
$excludepages = array(12, 14); // Notice, no quotes in the array declaration.
```

or

```
$excludepages = array();
$excludepages[] = 12;
$excludepages[] = 14;
```

Then in the get_posts it would look like:

```
$children = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' =>'page',
        'posts_per_page' =>-1,
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post__not_in' => $excludepages) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not with the `post__not_in` argument. It takes array, not a comma separated string:

> 'post__not_in'
>   (array) An array of post IDs not to retrieve. Note: a string of comma- separated IDs will NOT work.

More details: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/parse_query/

Your `$excludepages` returns `string(9) "'12','14'"`.

You should update it like:

```
$excludepages1 = "12,14";
$excludepages = explode(",", $excludepages1);

$children = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' =>'page',
    'posts_per_page' =>-1,
    'post_parent' => $post_id,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post__not_in' => $excludepages)
);
```

In above code, `$excludepages` will return:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(2) "12"
  [1]=> string(2) "14"
}
```